# textLabel in UITableViewHeaderFooterView isn't wide enough when I increase the kern vaue

Tags: ios, uitableview, frame, nsattributedstring

I have a table view with a bunch of sections in it. I want to change the text of the sections to make it smaller and give it more character spacing.

I have overridden the following method where I change the `.textLabel` property of the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` object:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        header.textLabel?.attributedText = header.textLabel?.text.flatMap {
            return NSAttributedString(string: $0, attributes: [
                .kern: 1.15
            ])
        }
        header.textLabel?.font = header.textLabel?.font.withSize(10)
    }
}
```

This works, but the label isn't wide enough for the added spacing between the characters. I tried calling `.sizeToFit` on both the `header` and the `textLabel` but it didn't work. I also tried changing the frame manually but that didn't work (the frame didn't update with my values for some reason.) How do I make the `textLabel` wider so that the text with the added character spacing can fit into it?

[image: Illustration of the issue]

Comment: How is defined your `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`? Xib? Storyboard? Did you set a constraint for the label? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701095/viewforheaderinsection-incorrect-width ?

Comment: @Larme UITableViewHeaderFooterView is an out of the box view provided by Apple. I also have the same issue where increasing the kerning seems to truncate the text. I think the only solution here is to make a custom view instead of using UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Comment: That's what I ended up doing as well